# Special characters in SharpPDF

Tags: c#, character, special-characters, sharppdf

I'm using sharpPDF dll (http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net) to create PDF's in C#. Everything works great but I don't get any special characters (actually these are Polish letters such as "ą, ć, ł, Ó...") in my output. I'm saving strings in that PDF.

Is there any way to get that working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SharpPDF has a lot of issues with special characters and there is no evolution planned for a correction of the special characters problem.

Sorry.